# Where is the OSGeo4W setup for QGIS 2.6.1?

Tags: qgis, installation, qgis-2.6, osgeo4w, qgis-2.7

The downloads [site](http://qgis.org/downloads/) for QGIS appears to only contain standalone installers. I want to install QGIS 2.6.1 using the OSGeo4W Network Installer (64 bit). When I do this currently, I install QGIS 2.7 which is not what I want.

Can I do this or must I download the OSGeo4W installer for QGIS 2.7 and then install the standalone for 2.6.1 and make that the default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current OSGEO4W 32-bit offers in advanced install::

```
qgis version 2.6.1-1
qgis-dev version 2.7.0-76
```

By clicking on the version number, you can switch back to 2.6.0-1 and 2.7.0-74

The 64-bit edition has

```
qgis, 2.6.1-1
qgis-dev, 2.7.0-73
```

Older versions are not available.

Comment: Thanks Andre, I deselected the 2.7 version and it's downloading. Will report back once it's installed and all is well.

Comment: Hmmm, getting some errors while installing it such as `Cannot find (null) file...`. I deselected several qgis-dev 2.7 components which is probably what's causing the error. Will only deselect the qgis-dev 2.7 and see what happens.

Comment: It would be better to unselect all, and select **only** qgis 2.6.1. Or choose a different target directory.

Comment: Yup, seems to be working now. Thanks for your help!